# How to get a click event outside an iframe when the iframe is clicked

Tags: iframe, jquery-ui-tabs

I would like to click in an iframe and open the link in a new tab with jQuery UI, but it does not work, and the new link opens in the same tab.
However, if I click on any point on the screen that is outside the iframe the new tab is created.

I appreciate if anyone knows help me

Regards,
Christian

---

The main page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        #tabs { margin-top: 1em; }
        #tabs li .ui-icon-close { float: left; margin: 0.4em 0.2em 0 0; cursor: pointer; }
        #add_tab { cursor: pointer; }
    </style>        

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.dock').find("a").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var name = $(event.currentTarget).text(), 
                    url  = $(event.currentTarget).attr("href");
                createNewTab(name, url, 5, true);
                return false;
            });

            $(this).click(function(e){  
                $('iframe').contents().find("a").click(function(event){ 
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var name = $(event.currentTarget).text(), 
                        url  = $(event.currentTarget).attr("href");
                    createNewTab(name, url, 5, true);
                    return false; 
                });
            });

            tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
            tabCounter = 1;         

            function selectNewTab() {
                $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active', -1);
            }
            function addTab(name, url) {
                tabCounter++;
                var tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remover Tab</span></li>";
                var id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
                    li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, name)),
                    tabContentHtml = '<iframe id="ifr" class="tabs-iframe" src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="400" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center"></iframe>';
                tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
                tabs.append("<div id='" + id + "'>" + tabContentHtml + "</div>");
                tabs.tabs("refresh");
            }
            function createNewTab(name, url, size, checkTabExists) {
                addTab(name, url);
                selectNewTab();
            }           
        });
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>Tab 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dock">
        <a href="another-page.html">New Tab</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The another page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="http://www.microsoft.com">Click Here</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible in the way you want, The javascript Same Origin Policy will prevent any javascript code to access the iFrame if its not on the same domain (Domains, protocols and ports must match).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I agree with you if I had already opened the link from another domain. I did another test by creating a third page in the same domain that also did not work. It seems to me that the problem is related to the click event, because if I click somewhere on the screen outside the iframe it will work. In another test, I tried to set the focus () to another element on the screen or run a click () on another element programmatically, but that also did not work.

Answer (score 1):

@ChristianB you are not attaching the click event to your iFrames when they are created, you are trying to attach the click event to the existing iFrames. I have tried to change the code in your function addTab;

I have attached an id attribute to your iFrames, so I can attach the click event to the iFrame document once iFrame is created.

Try This:

```
        function addTab(name, url) {
            tabCounter++;
            var tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remover Tab</span></li>";
            var id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
                li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, name)),
                tabContentHtml = '<iframe id="ifr' + tabCounter + '" class="tabs-iframe" src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="400" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center"></iframe>';
            tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
            tabs.append("<div id='" + id + "'>" + tabContentHtml + "</div>");
            tabs.tabs("refresh");

            //Add the Link Click to newly created iFrame

            $('#ifr'+tabCounter).ready(function(e) {
              /* This does not work with chrome
              $('#ifr'+tabCounter).contents().find("a").bind('click', function(event){ 
              */
              //Below throws an exception in chrome, but still works
              $('#ifr'+tabCounter.contentWindow.document.body).find(a).bind('click', function(event){ 
                  //event.preventDefault();
                  var name = $(event.currentTarget).text(); 
                  var url  = $(event.currentTarget).attr("href");
                  createNewTab(name, url, 5, true);
                  return false; 
              });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit for your feedback. I post a new answer putting your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mohit Padalia. You have helped me a lot. I tried using your code but did not work. I believe it worked for you, because the function selectNewTab(​​) was not working. In this case, I add a policy to force the selection of the new tab created. Note that when running the code below the new tab is selected and you click "ckick here" the new link will open in the same tab. However, if you click anywhere on the screen outside the iframe and then click the link that will work, and the new tab is created.

Kind Regards,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        #tabs { margin-top: 1em; }
        #tabs li .ui-icon-close { float: left; margin: 0.4em 0.2em 0 0; cursor: pointer; }
        #add_tab { cursor: pointer; }
    </style>        

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.dock').find("a").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var name = $(event.currentTarget).text(), 
                    url  = $(event.currentTarget).attr("href");
                createNewTab(name, url, 5, true);
                return false;
            });

            $(this).click(function(e){  
                $('iframe').contents().find("a").click(function(event){ 
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var name = $(event.currentTarget).text(), 
                        url  = $(event.currentTarget).attr("href");
                    createNewTab(name, url, 5, true);
                    return false; 
                });
            });

            tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
            tabCounter = 1;         

            function selectNewTab() {
                $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active', -1);
            }
            function addTab(name, url) {
                tabCounter++;
                var tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remover Tab</span></li>";
                var id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
                    li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, name)),
                    tabContentHtml = '<iframe id="ifr' + tabCounter + '" class="tabs-iframe" src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="400" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center"></iframe>';
                tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
                tabs.append("<div id='" + id + "'>" + tabContentHtml + "</div>");
                tabs.tabs("refresh");

                //Add force select new tab 
                tabs.tabs('option', 'active', -1);

                //Add the Link Click to newly created iFrame

                $('#ifr'+tabCounter).ready(function(e) {
                  /* This does not work with chrome
                  $('#ifr'+tabCounter).contents().find("a").bind('click', function(event){ 
                  */
                  //Below throws an exception in chrome, but still works
                  $('#ifr'+tabCounter.contentWindow.document.body).find(a).bind('click', function(event){ 
                      //event.preventDefault();
                      var name = $(event.currentTarget).text(); 
                      var url  = $(event.currentTarget).attr("href");
                      createNewTab(name, url, 5, true);
                      return false; 
                  });
                });
            }

            function createNewTab(name, url, size, checkTabExists) {
                addTab(name, url);
                //selectNewTab();
            }           
        });
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>Tab 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dock">
        <a href="another-page.html">New Tab</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```